# Проблема с выводом таблиц и select

Tags: php, html, mysql

подскажите пожалуйста. Есть два select, выбираю их и нажимаю - выводит одну таблицу, выбираю ещё другое значение select`a, выводит одну и ещё предыдущую таблицу. Понимаю, что сложно выглядит, но поймите уж.

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form_cat">
                <select name="category" style="width: 200px;">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Оберіть критерії</option>
                    <option value="all">Вибрати всі</option>
                    <option value="congrat">Привітання</option> <!--RED- -->
                    <option value="diagnostic">Діагностика</option><!--green- -->
                    <option value="question">Вирішення питання</option><!--blue- -->
                    <option value="bye">Прощання</option><!--pink- -->
                    <option value="criteria">Загальні критерії</option><!--yellow- -->
                    <option value="conflict">Конфлікт</option><!--zero- -->
                </select>
                <select name="operators" style="width: 200px;">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Оберіть оператора</option>
                    <?php 
                        $sqli = mysqli_query($conn_oa, "SHOW TABLES FROM ".$dBNameOa);
                        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($sqli)) 
                        {
                            echo'<option value="'. $rows[0] .'">'. $rows[0] .'</option>';
                        }
                     ?>
                </select>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            if ($selected_category = "congrat") {
                $sql_support1 = "SELECT `clerk_id`, `like_1` , `like_2` , `like_3` FROM ".$selected_operator." WHERE like_1 > 3 OR like_2 > 3 OR like_3 > 3 ;";
                $result_support1 = mysqli_query($conn_oa, $sql_support1);
                echo '
                <ul>
                <table class="features-table table-support" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="grey">Привітання</th>
                </thead>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ідентифікація абонента / клієнта:'; 
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_support1)) {
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_1'];
                echo '</td>
                <td>Звернення за ім\'ям:'; 
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_2'];
                echo '</td>
                <td>Привітання:'; 
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_3'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr></table></ul>';
            }
        }
                if ($selected_category = "diagnostic") {
                $sql_support1 = "SELECT `clerk_id`, `like_1` , `like_2` , `like_3` FROM ".$selected_operator." WHERE like_1 > 3 OR like_2 > 3 OR like_3 > 3 ;";
                $result_support1 = mysqli_query($conn_oa, $sql_support1);
                echo '
                <ul>
                <table class="features-table table-support" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="grey">dia</th>
                </thead>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Ідентифікація абонента / клієнта:'; 
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_support1)) {
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_1'];
                echo '</td>
                <td>Звернення за ім\'ям:'; 
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_2'];
                echo '</td>
                <td>Привітання:'; 
                echo '<br>'; echo $row2['like_3'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr></table></ul>';
            }
        }
```

Выводит почему то при выборе другого select - первую и вторую таблицу. Подскажите, в чём проблема? Я буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что вы условие не правильное делаете, используйте нормальное IDE типа PhpStorm который подсветит вам эти косяки

```
if ($selected_category = "diagnostic")
if ($selected_category = "congrat")
```

эти условия будут выполнятся всегда !!! нужно

```
if ($selected_category == "diagnostic")
if ($selected_category == "congrat")
```

Comment: Теперь их вообще не выводит, как быть то? В чём ещё проблема? А с равно  - я действительно не досмотрел. За phpstorm - благодарю. Но подскажите где ещё прокол? Очень огромное спасибо.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, совсем уж не вижу где не так.

Comment: вы не уничтожаете предыдущую таблицу же.